# DNS breaks when VPN is turned off

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn, l2tp

I have an L2TP VPN set up on Ubuntu 18.04 (set up similar to [this](https://help.vpntunnel.com/support/solutions/articles/5000782608-vpntunnel-l2tp-installation-guide-for-ubuntu-18-04-)). Whenever I turn the VPN off through the settings after using it for a while, my DNS seems to break entirely. For example, Firefox reports "we can't connect to the server at [address]" and `ping` reports "Name or service not known". IP addresses work fine, suggesting that it's a DNS problem.

My work around is to disconnect from the network and reconnect, which restores my DNS access.

Does anybody know what the problem might be and if there's a better solution? I would like to be able to more ergonomically choose when to use the VPN.

Comment: Post your 'cat /etc/resolv.conf' before connecting to the VPN, when connected and after disconnecting, and 'ls /etc/ppp'

Answer (score 1):

To avoid Ubuntu bug [LP#1778946](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1778946) which breaks DNS resolution after disconnecting the VPN connection, install the resolvconf package :

```
sudo apt install resolvconf
```

Or install a newer version of the network-manager-l2tp package from the following PPA:

- https://launchpad.net/~nm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp